# Simple jQuery gallery which can load content dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic-data, gallery

I need some jQuery plugin, tutorial or guidelines to create **simple image gallery** which content could be loaded dynamically, it would display one image at the time, and that image would be changed by sliding it to the left or right.

I have tried jCarousel, but I could not manage to make it show only one image at the time with dynamically loaded content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage the jCarousel itself to achieve your requirement of showing one image at a time by following these steps.

1. Set the jCarousel configuration option of 'scroll' as '1'. This option will make your carousel to scroll only one image at a time.
2. Then change the skin styles(width, height and padding) of image containers according to your image dimensions.

   For example if your images are of size 100x100 then change the image container's width and height as 100px and 100px and add some padding like 10px so that only one image will appear at a time.

Try this solution and let me know if you are facing any problem while making these changes.

Siva ...

Comment: That worked out thanx!, but maybe you also know how to dynamically load different galleries?

Comment: If you mean to load the gallery data(i.e images) dynamically refer the 'Dynamic Examples' section of http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples page. 

If you mean to load more dynamic galleries in a single page, you need to refer http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_multiple.html with the above examples. 

Check the corresponding source code of these example pages then only you will get an idea to handle the jCarousel according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I also working on jquery slider at this time and I use this one - http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/

It's such a cool stuf and fully customizeable.